# ASP.NET Core MVC exception on add migration on 6.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using the ASP.NET Core MVC project and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity v6.0 and when I am running add migration it shows an exception

An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`3[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`3[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.RoleStore`3[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext,System.String]'.)
Unable to create an object of type 'DbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, seems like you are missing some dependencies and the system is not able to inject the correct implementation for certain interfaces. Register missing services in the `Program.cs` class,

Have you added `services.AddDbContext()` with the correct connection settings?

Comment: yes i have added                                                                                                                      var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

Comment: @MuhammadAzibAli Do you have multiple DB Contexts? Are you running the migration command from the folder having the entities and the context?

Comment: no, I have only one DBcontext but now my web application is running